# Figure out Pattern for a Recursive Function

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, recursion

I have difficulty to understand a pattern for this code. I tested this function and I know for input Ack(3,2) this function circles 541 times, so it must have a pattern for solving this problem. Please help me find the pattern.

```
public static int Ack(int m,int n)
{
    if (n < 0 || m < 0) return 0;
    else if (m == 0) return n + 1;
    else if (n == 0) return Ack(m - 1, 1);
    else return Ack(m-1,Ack(m,n-1));
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for help to recreate a non-recursive function?

Comment: thats ackerman function - which grows really really fast and it's inverse is useful in analyzing asymptotics of Union Find data structure. You can get closed formula @wiki (it uses Knuth arrow notation) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: NO I Want To know A pattern For This Code So I Can Solve this Without Writing this Code and Run it

Comment: Thanks fex That's Really Helps

Comment: What do you mean by pattern? If you are trying to find out the problem the code solves, someone already posted a link

Comment: He probably mean a "closed form".

Answer (score 0):

Here is some non-recursive python code that computes the same thing (note that it requires a stack-like data structure):

```
def ack(m,n):
    if n < 0 or m < 0:
         return 0

    next_m = []
    while m != 0 or (m==0 and next_m!=[]):
        if (m==0 and next_m!=[]):
            m = next_m.pop()
            n = n+1
            continue
        if n==0:
            m = m-1
            n = 1
        else:
            n = n-1
            next_m.append(m-1)

    return n+1
```